# React Native - AWS S3 Upload Image Error: URL.hostname is not implemented

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload photos using React Native, AWS Amplify and S3.  I'm getting the following error:

```
LOG  [Error: URL.hostname is not implemented]
```

I've tried almost every method found here, and I haven't been able to come to any conclusions.

```js
  const uploadResource = async () => {
    if (isLoading) return;
    setisLoading(true);
    const img = await fetchResourceFromURI(asset.uri);
    return Storage.put(asset.uri, img, {
      level: 'public',
      contentType: asset.type,
      progressCallback(uploadProgress) {
        setProgressText(
          `Progress: ${Math.round(
            (uploadProgress.loaded / uploadProgress.total) * 100,
          )} %`,
        );
        console.log(
          `Progress: ${uploadProgress.loaded}/${uploadProgress.total}`,
        );
      },
    })
      .then(res => {
        setProgressText('Upload Done: 100%');
        setAsset(null);
        setisLoading(false);
        Storage.get(res.key)
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(err => {
            setProgressText('Upload Error');
            console.log(err);
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setisLoading(false);
        setProgressText('Upload Error');
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

```json
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.19",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^6.0.4",
    "react-native": "^0.68.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.19",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^6.0.4",
```